# How to transfer the properties of one variable to another easily in python?

Tags: python

Here I have 2 `classes A` and `B`,

```
class A(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.a1=0
    self.a2=0
    self.a3=0
class B(object):
  def GenerateA(self):
    self.a=A()
    #some codes go here
    return self.a
a=A()
a.a1=1
a.a2=2
a.a3=3
b=B()
ainb=b.GenerateA()
print(ainb)
ainb.a1=a.a1
ainb.a2=a.a2
ainb.a3=a.a3
print(ainb)
```

`class B` has a function of `GenerateA()`, which can return a empty instance of `class A`(but I don't know what it exactly did since they are from vendor). `class A` is an interface class, which let `B` knowing some values for further calculations. here I need to setup `ainb` of its every property. I can do like this directly:

```
ainb.a1=1
ainb.a2=2
ainb.a3=3
```

or I can setup by doing

```
a=A()
a.a1=1
a.a2=2
a.a3=3
ainb.a1=a.a1
ainb.a2=a.a2
ainb.a3=a.a3
```

I hope to setup `ainb` in a easy way, so that I can keep its address unchanged, I suppose the `copy.deepcopy()` method will totally replace the address, which I don't want to.
Do you have any suggestions?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `deepcopy() method will totally replace the address` what address?

Comment: is it allowed for you to change the structure of the classes A and B ?

Comment: sorry, maybe I am totally wrong, I think deepcopy() will deeply new a instance from the original one, so it will generate a totally different address of a new instance of class A, correct?

Comment: If you want two different copies, they will have different address. If you want it to have same address, they will be two variables pointing to the same reference. What is the issue? Based on what I got, your statements contradicts it. *As you want copy with same address*

Comment: @Moinuddin Quadri, no, the class A and B are from vendor, I only know some of the properties and functions. I have print(ainb) to show their address, it will not change if use my codes above. This is the address GenerateA() gave me, which I don't want to change. But maybe my understanding is wrong.

Comment: I only want a easy way to replace ainb.a1=a.a1
ainb.a2=a.a2
ainb.a3=a.a3, since here actually there are lots of properies a1,a2,a3...,an, I hope there is a clever way to avoid write all them down. In c/c++ there might be easy way to copy the content of original adress to the new address. this is what I am looking for.

Comment: Do you want to assign ALL of ```a```'s attribute values to ```ainb```?  Or just some of them?

Comment: @wwii, I think it's a good question. I believe I can only setup as many attributes as I want, others can be kept as default. And then copy the whole instance of a to ainb. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To copy/transfer the value for all attributes from `a` to `ainb`.

Probably should filter out all of `a`'s methods and double-underscore attributes

```
attrs = [attr for attr in dir(a) if not attr.startswith('__') and not callable(attr)]
```

Then iterate through the remaining attributes and use [getattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) and [setattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr):

```
for attr in attrs:
    try:
        setattr(ainb, attr, getattr(a, attr))
    except AttributeError:
        print 'ainb does not have', attr
```

---

Similarly, if you have a container with attribute/value pairs:

```
setup = [('a1', 1), ('a2', 2), ('a3', 3)]
for attr, value in setup:
    try:
        setattr(ainb, attr, value)
    except AttributeError:
        print 'ainb does not have', attr
```